# Suggestions for remote desktop solution

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop, development

I have a laptop and a desktop computer. I am tired of having two different machines. When I am away from home I would like to use my laptop as if it were my home computer.

I do a lot of game development (C#/C++) so the solution would need to be capable of showing direct3d. It does not need to be real-time just fast enough to be interactive (hopefully > 5fps).

Also, my laptop is a MacBook pro however I do run Windows on it as well as OS X and VMware fusion.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx). Minimal configuration required and I've played fullscreen games on other people's computers with it remotely, so your Direct3D requirement should be fine. Albeit the FPS wasn't the best, but you can turn down the resolution and definitely achieve at least 5fps+.

There is also [RDP for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx), not sure if it supports D3D though.

other programs which require a bit of configuration:

- [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)
- [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [StreamMyGame](http://streammygame.com). It works for playing games remotely so I would assume it would meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for in terms of being "tired of having two machines" - are you wanting to remove the desktop computer from the equation?

Or was you thinking of leaving the desktop on and using a "remote desktop" facility to effectively control that machine from the comfort of your laptop?

In answer to both

1) If you want to remove the desktop but still want something separate for development, why not consider using a Virtual Machine? Software such as [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is free and compatible with Intel based Mac's.

2) Software such as VNC will allow you to run a server on your desktop and "remote desktop" into it from your mac, effectively giving you a window into your home computer

I'm hoping this sheds a little light into what you are after?

Comment: I want to remove the laptop form the equation. I want to use my home desktop computer from my laptop. (Laptop < Desktop when it comes to speed and hdd space)

Comment: so basically you want to use the laptop as a go-between between yourself and your desktop computer. 

Any remote desktop software will do that for you, I've had little experience so I can't offer too much of a comment but I think VNC will do the job you're after. 

The bottleneck will be your network connection more than anything but it should be alright around the house

Comment: It is not true that any solution will work. I have used remote desktop solutions which do not even attempt to send any windows which are using the graphics device. However, I will look into VNC