# how do you remote desktop to mac osx from windows?

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Remote desktop to Mac from various platforms (Windows, Ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/117419/remote-desktop-to-mac-from-various-platforms-windows-ubuntu)
>   [Fast VNC from Windows to Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/28546/fast-vnc-from-windows-to-mac)

Hey any one know of a free application i can use to remote desktop to my mac from windows?

Comment: Look at  http://superuser.com/questions/62780/suggestions-for-remote-desktop-solution , also at http://superuser.com/questions/28546/fast-vnc-from-windows-to-mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as a cross platform solution PC -> Mac, VNC is the best solution. The slowness is likely due to a combination of the speed of your Internet connection, the resolution on your Mac, and the color depth you've chosen on your Mac.

See [How do I… Connect Microsoft Windows systems to a Macintosh network?](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-do-i-connect-microsoft-windows-systems-to-a-macintosh-network)

Comment: VNC has multiple problems: sometimes really slow (in LAN!), copy & paste of text doesn't work, no drag & drop of files like in Remote Desktop, problems with the keyboard because of layout problems between Windows & Mac and localization. Any solutions to this? The only alternative would be TeamViewer I think.

Answer (score 3):

Use VNC. On the Mac enable VNC access in `System Preferences` => `Sharing` => `Screen Sharing`. On the PC you need to install a VNC client such as RealVNC.

Answer (score 3):

Another option: [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)

Simple download and run for client, no installation needed for impromptu help sessions... (Still, you can install if you want to).

Works well enough, and is free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Any VNC client should be able to connect to a VNC server on the Mac.

See http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2007/05/14/a-vnc-server-is-included-in-mac-os-x-104/ for configuring VNC on the mac

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, do you mean to remotely control a Mac OS X machine?  Are you on a local LAN or over the internet?

I use the built in VNC server on Mac (System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Management > Computer Settings... > VNC Viewers may control screen with this password) and from Windows, Linux, or w/e I use a VNC client such as Tight VNC on Windows or vnc4viewer on Ubuntu.

If you are controlling over the internet you might look into logmein.  I use that and it seems to be very reliable.  It's not as fast as gotomypc in my experience but it's free.