# Accessing mac mini server from win 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, remote-control, mac-mini, remote-login

I have a mac mini server with MacOSX 10.9. I want to connect to the server with my win 7 laptop in a different user. Then there will be two users working on different accounts seperately. Is that possible?

So far I tried splashtop, vnc viewer and teamviewer on different ports. When I log both accounts in, open this remote connectors and change my user I lost connection.

In short, I want to work with two users one with win7 remote connection(on the same LAN) and other directly connected mac mini user.

How is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to access the GUI specifically, or just the machine?

Comment: I want both user can control the machine. For example both will use applications without any conflict

Comment: You can use `ssh` and do `x forwarding`, have you researched that at all?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/142181/how-do-you-remote-desktop-to-mac-osx-from-windows which in itself is marked as being a duplicate.  Its Turtles all the way down.

Comment: Are you trying to have both users logged into the **same** account on the Mac?

Comment: two different accounts and two different users